# how to return a dataframe if one of rows in column match certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe that i want it to return me a dataframe if one of the values is high

```
df

a     b    c     d    e    f 
high low  high  low  high low
low  low  low   low  low  high
low  low  low   low  low  low
```

I know how to do it if we filter it in column

```
df[df[a]=="high"]
```

If i tried to loop the process but it won't work

```
for column in df.columns:
    df_high=df[df[column]=="high"]
```

df_high return 0 rows.
Expected result:

```
 a    b   c    d   e    f
high low high low high low
low  low low  low low  high
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) along with [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) along `axis=1` to create a *boolean mask* then use this `mask` to filter out the rows in dataframe:

```
mask = df.eq('high').any(axis=1)
df1 = df[mask]
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

     a    b     c    d     e     f
0  high  low  high  low  high   low
1   low  low   low  low   low  high
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['high', 'low', 'low'], 'b':['low', 'high', 'low']})
df.loc[(df=='high').sum(axis=1) > 0]
```